# ETF and Mutual Funds turnover tax analysis

Tags: untagged

I am looking for tax-analysis for several ETFs and Mutual Funds. Morningstar used to have a tool that would show estimates of pretax returns and tax-adjusted returns for many funds (depending on their turnover), see screenshot below:

[image]

This tool seems to have been either discontinued or it was moved to somewhere, where I cannot find it. Does anyone know of any (ideally free) tool that would do such ballpark analysis?

Comment: It would be great that whoever downvoted would explain why.